# create() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, django-models, django-views

models.py

```
class UserAttributes(models.Model):

    airport = models.ForeignKey('airport.Airport', related_name='user_attributes_airport', on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True, blank=True)
    location = PointField(blank=True, null=True)
    user =  models.ForeignKey(
        'users.AerosimpleUser', related_name='user_attributes',
        on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, blank=True)
```

views.py

```
class LocationViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):

    serializer_class=LocationRetrieveSerializer
    http_method_names = ['get', 'post', 'patch', 'put']

    def get_permissions(self):
            switcher = {
                'create': [IsAuthenticated],
                'list': [IsAuthenticated],
                'retrieve': [IsAuthenticated],
                'update': [IsAuthenticated],
                'partial_update': [IsAuthenticated],
            }
            self.permission_classes = switcher.get(self.action, [IsAdminUser])
            return super(self.__class__, self).get_permissions()
    def get_queryset(self):
        return UserAttributes.objects.filter(
            airport__id=self.request.user.aerosimple_user.airport_id).order_by('pk')
```

serializers.py

```
class LocationRetrieveSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = UserAttributes
        fields = '__all__'

    def create(self, validated_data):
    

        if UserAttributes.objects.filter(user_id=self.context["request"].data['user'],airport_id=self.context["request"].data['airport']).exists():
            obj=UserAttributes.objects.get(user_id=self.context["request"].data['user'])
            obj.location=self.context["request"].data['location']
            obj.save()
            return obj
        user_attributes = UserAttributes.objects.create(validated_data)
        return user_attributes
```

what changes should i make

Comment: Please add the full error traceback to your question!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using drf docs for reference on [saving instances](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/#saving-instances) try unpacking the `validated_data` before returning it:

```
    def create(self, validated_data):
    

        if UserAttributes.objects.filter(user_id=self.context["request"].data['user'],airport_id=self.context["request"].data['airport']).exists():
            obj=UserAttributes.objects.get(user_id=self.context["request"].data['user'])
            obj.location=self.context["request"].data['location']
            obj.save()
            return obj
        user_attributes = UserAttributes.objects.create(**validated_data)
```